# Will I receive OOM errors if I run too many applications in the same process?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-memory

I have twenty little Dashclock extensions running on my phone. Each extension is actually a Service that is always running.

Currently each of these extensions use 2.5 MB each to run, which brings my memory consumption to about 50MB.

I thought that maybe I could optimize resources if each of them ran in the same process. Each one id currently a separate APK and therefore has it's own process.

I haven't been able to understand the maximum size of the heap in Android - is it about 16MB per process or per app? If I changed the manifest files to make all these 20 services run in the same process, would this cause OOM errors?

Comment: Why the downvote without a reason? If this isn't a constructive question to the community in it's current state, I'd be more than willing to revise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran 30 processes in the same process byt setting the `android:shareUserID` and the "android:process" in the manifest. I was able to run them properly without any OOM errors or class-loading errors.

I haven't used the `android:largeHeap` flag in the manifest and my application is now using 40M of memory.

I'm running Cyanogenmod on a Nexus 5 and haven't changed any values in the `build.prop` file. My heap-size on the device is 16M.

Unless someone has an explanation of why this is happening, I'll consider this to be the answer that you do not get OOM errors and the heap-space is on a per-application basis, not per process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["largeHeap"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) flag in the AndroidManifest to get additional memory.

Unfortunately, I don't see any hard numbers as to how much memory this increases your heap to, especially since it depends on the device. You could always use [`getMemoryClass` on the `ActivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) object to limit the number of widgets that the user can run.

Comment: The `largeHeap` flag might push the heap size to 24M (or even a bit more on some devices), but that still wouldn't be enough. I haven't found an authoritative answer as to whether the limits are per-application or per-process.

Comment: From the "largeHeap" page it says, "Whether your application's processes should be created with a large Dalvik heap. This applies to all processes created for the application." So this means that it's on a per process basis. Applications can use more, but I don't know what the limit per application is. Worst case scenario, you could use the NDK which has no memory limit, but that's a lot of extra effort.